# Executing Python script from PHP and insert in mysql

Tags: python, php, mysql

I have a php script that executes a python script and returns the data back and it is stored in mysql. It's working fine but when the data is stored in the database it inserts an additional blank row. My question would be, how could I make so that it stores only the actual data I recieve.

This is part of the python script

```
##ser.write(sync)
    ser.write(counters)
    a = ser.read(30)
    state = binascii.hexlify(a)
    asd = re.sub(rb'([0-9, a-z, A-Z])(?!$)', rb'\1,', state)
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1/sastest/meters.php'
    x = requests.post(url, data = asd)
    print(asd)
```

And this is from the PHP

```
    passthru("meters.py");

    $incomingData = file_get_contents("php://input");


    $qry1 = "INSERT INTO machtest(data)
                values('".$incomingData."')";

    mysqli_query($conn,$qry1);
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Does the PHP call the Python or does the Python call the PHP?

Comment: PHP calls the py script ```passthru("meters.py");``` meters.py is the called file. the py script is interrogating a device through serial communication

Comment: But then in the Python you have `url = 'http://127.0.0.1/sastest/meters.php'`.  Is meters.php a _different_ PHP file from what is shown above?

Comment: Php file is called meters.php yes and meters.py the python file

Comment: So don't you see that you have a PHP file that calls a Python file, that in turn calls the original PHP file again, and so on and so on

Comment: When I call meters.php it activates meters.py. meters.py interrogates a devices and sends the data back to meters.php

Comment: The talking part is just fine, the mysql storing is the problem because when the php file gets the data it stores 2 rows in the database, one is with the correct data and one row empty, I don't want the empty row

Comment: meters.py does two different things.  First, it initiates a _new request_ to meters.php (which causes that file to run again _from the beginning_) and then it outputs some content which `passthru()` then pipes to the screen.  I'm actually somewhat surprised that this isn't causing an infinite loop, but the system must be smart enough to recognize this and abort.  Just call your meters.py directly (not from PHP) and you should get the desired result.

Comment: I'm closing the serial communication from meters.py after interrogation and data is sent that's why there could be no infinite loop. I am calling from the php file because right now both files are local, but the intent will be that the device I am intterogating will not be local and the python script will be on the device and the php file on a server. If I am running the py script alone it works just fine by the way.

Comment: "If I am running the py script alone it works just fine by the way."  That's exactly my point.  Your py script _is calling your PHP script_.  Every call to your PHP script is running your INSERT statement.  Your PHP script is being called multiple times.  That's why you are getting multiple rows inserted.  If you really can't call the py directly (I don't understand why you can't), then split your PHP into two files. One file that _calls_ the py script, and another than handles the request _from_ the py script.

Comment: _"meters.py interrogates a devices and sends the data back to meters.php"_ ...no, not really. What is actually does is make a **new, separate** request to meters.php. Please understand how HTTP works. If you wanted to send a response back to the instance of meters.php which made the call to python, then you simply have to output some data. By doing `requests.post` you are creating a new instance of meters.php. That PHP script will then run again, separately, from the beginning, even while the earlier one has not yet completed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to do that. The reason I can't call it directly is because the python file is on a remote device and the php file is on a server.

Comment: Calling the python script from a separate php file works great. Thank you verry much for your help. @PatrickQ

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

From comments we discover the overall process:

> When I call *meters.php* it activates *meters.py*. *meters.py* interrogates a devices and sends the data back to *meters.php*

Because PHP's [`passthru`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) does not  support output return but a similar function [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) does as array object with each line as elements, use that instead and do not have Python post back a response. Of course, always run parameterization when interacting with databases and passing input values.

**Python**  *(meters.py)*

```py
ser.write(counters)
a = ser.read(30)
state = binascii.hexlify(a)
asd = re.sub(rb'([0-9, a-z, A-Z])(?!$)', rb'\1,', state)

print(asd)
```

**PHP** *(meters.php)*

```php
// USE output ARG
exec(command = "meters.py", output = $incomingData);

// USE PARAMETERIZATION
$qry = "INSERT INTO machtest (data) VALUES (%s)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($qry);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $incomingData[0]);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

[See mysqli prepared statement docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

---

Alternatively, have Python run all processing including device and database interaction. Then, have PHP call the .py script:

**Python**  *(meters.py)*

```py
import mysql.connector        # USE ANY MySQL DB-API. THIS IS AN EXAMPLE
...

### INTERROGATE DEVICE
ser.write(counters)
a = ser.read(30)
state = binascii.hexlify(a)
asd = re.sub(rb'([0-9, a-z, A-Z])(?!$)', rb'\1,', state)

### APPEND TO DATABASE
# OPEN CONNECTION AND CURSOR
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='mydatabase',
                               user='root', password='pwd')
cur = conn.cursor()

# USE PARAMETERIZATION   
qry = "INSERT INTO machtest (data) VALUES (%s)"
cur.execute(qry, (asd,))
conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

[See MySQL cursor execute docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

**PHP** *(meters.php)*

```php
// NO NEED FOR output
passthru(command = "meters.py");
```

Comment: It looks like you mixed up Python and PHP. The PHP example is completely broken.